# What is the difference between swapping with and assigning an empty vector to an existing vector?

Tags: c++, memory

What is the difference between:

```
// bb has a million elements
vector<B>().swap(bb);
//and
bb = Vector<B>();
```

What happens under the hood?

Comment: _"What happens under the hood?"_ A copy or move operation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why is the memory freed properly?

Comment: Why not? `std::vector` was designed to manage that properly.

Comment: So why do I see in code `Vector<B>().swap(bb)` instead of simply `bb = Vector<B>();`, What is the difference?

Comment: `swap()` is more efficient than taking a copy.

Comment: So what happens under the hood? How are they different?

Comment: `swap()` is implemented just exchanging the internally managed pointers to the vector data.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D

Comment: Assignment is always well-defined. `swap` is UB if the allocators do not compare equal and do not propagate on swap. But I suspect that's not what you are asking about...

Comment: @T.C. Undefined behavior? You make it sound dangerous! All I wanna know is why people advice to use swap (implicitly) instead of assigning an empty vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks but it doesn't explain what actually happens under the hood. 
A good answer would explain how is allocating an empty vector and assigning it different from swapping with one. Thus unveiling the mystery behind the common use of swap to empty vectors (instead of assignments).

Comment: @T.C. You probably meant IB (Implementation defined) vs UB (undefined)

Comment: I meant what I wrote.

Comment: @T.C. No need to be angry, it was merely an attempt to get you to elaborate. When you say it's undefined, it sounds like anything could happen when you use swap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the semantics of the two are slightly different:

- swap will exchange the content of the two vectors
- assigning will either copy the content of the right-hand side vector to the left-hand side vector or move/steal it depending on the version of C++ you are using and some extra parameters

---

Now, specifically with your example and `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<B>().swap(bb);
```

This will:

- create an empty vector (let's call it `__tmp`)
- swap the content of both vectors (ie, swap their internal buffers)
- destroy `__tmp`, along with the former content of `bb`

The result is that `bb` is left empty.

On the other hand:

```
bb = std::vector<B>();
```

will overwrite the content of `bb` with that of an empty vector. Depending on whether you are using C++03 or C++11 (or superior) the behavior will be different:

- in C++03, the elements of `bb` are destructed but `bb` probably retains its capacity (that is, it has memory allocated for a million elements as before)
- in C++11, the internal buffer of `std::vector<B>` may replace that of `bb` or not; there is no formal obligation that I know of

As a result, while `bb` will be empty, it is not clear what its internal capacity ends up being.

---

Historically, `std::vector<B>().swap(bb)` was the recommended way of clearing the content of `bb` when one wanted to make sure to reduce its capacity (to free memory up).

Nowadays (post C++11), there is an explicit `shrink_or_fit` method to do so, but because it is not mandated to actually reduce capacity and because old habits die hard, you may still encounter the form.

Comment: Thanks, so in lament terms swap is the only one to guarantee we free memory from the heap. :D

Answer (score 1):

Memory leak is memory that you can't access due to missing pointer.
A vector is container that designed to execute a dynamic allocation to avoid this memory leak, so you, as a user, don't need to deal with it.